# psexec error code -1073740771

Tags: remote-access, psexec

I'm trying to open up a Unity3D game.exe that is on a remote computer through my main desktop. I had tried to do this through a batch file, but was advised to try [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) in its place.

So far, I've brought the Psexec program into my game.exe folder. I run the command line required to open the program and the window opens up for a fraction of a second before closing down due to an error. The error code it gives is: -1073740771.

I tried googling what this error actually is but I can't find anything. Does anyone know what this error relates to?

The command line I type is as follows:

```
psexec \\OtherComputer -i C:\Administrator\Users\Desktop\TargetFolder\Target.exe
```

I even tried the above line with -d after the -i, quotes around the C:... but it all results in the same thing.

Comment: Is your entire game self contained within game.exe?  Or are there supporting DLLs, resources and so forth in other folders?

Comment: It's a Unity game exe. So there is the main exe plus a folder containing the other resources it needs.

Answer (score 1):

`PSExec` wont know about other game resources that live without side the EXE.  It will simply copy `game.exe` to the remote machine and execute it.

Try deleting or renaming the resource folder and running it on your local machine - it should do the same thing as its doing on the remote machine.

You cant do what you want with `psexec` unless the entire application is self contained within one single `.exe` file.

You may be able to manually copy the resource folders if you have admin access to the other machines and administrative shares are enabled, then execute with psexec using the `-w` option:

- Copy the files to `\\OtherComputer\C$\MyGame`
- Run `psexec \\OtherComputer -w C:\MyGame -i C:\Administrator\Users\Desktop\TargetFolder\Target.exe`

Might work ;o)

Comment: Thank you for that. I tried, but the same issue and error code appear.

Comment: Copy and paste fingers went a bit mad there.  Copy the entire lot to `\\OtherComputer\c$\MyGame` and then run `psexec \\OtherComputer -i -w C:\\MyGame C:\MyGame\\Target.exe`.  Do you mind if I ask why you are trying to do this? Playing from a-far?!

Answer (score 0):

Use the -h parameter to elevate the permissions.